Microsoft Excel 2 way link between 3 sheets
I am trying to create a workbook with the following two way link between 3 sheets.
Example:
Sheet 1 cell A1 input - yes, sheet 2 & 3 cell A1 on both show "yes"
Sheet 2 cell A1 input - no, sheet 1 & 3 cell A1 on both show "no"
Sheet 3 cell A1 input - maybe, sheet 1 & 2 cell A1 on both show "maybe"
I would like to do this for a specific range on all 3 sheets in the same workbook.
I am not experienced in VBA but am willing to try any suggestion to get this working.
Any assistance would be appreaciated.

Welcome to Superuser. Please note that this site is not a script-writing service. I recommend that you search this site and the general web regarding connecting sheets in the way you describe, and once you have some code and data, we may be able to help you fill in your knowledge gaps at that point.

It sounds like you could do this with simple formulas. Have you tried that?

@bugdrown, formulas cannot work if he wants to be able to edit on all of the sheets. He'd basically edit the cells and hence replace the formula there with text

@bugdrown, thank you for the suggestion bu I have tried formulas and have been unable to find one that meets my needs

It is not possible to have a cell contain both a formula and a cell. It will have to be a VBA solution that monitors the cells in question. You can use a Worksheet.Change event to watch for changes and then check if the target of those changes is one of the cells you care about. If it is, then  you can go make whatever changes you like to other cells. You probably want to disable event listening (Application.EnableEvents = False) while you do this or else those changes could trigger the Worksheet.Change event again. Just be sure to set that back to TRUE when you're done.

It seems to me that the most convenient way to achieve the expected effect is to group the sheets. If the sheets are grouped, any change you make to any of them will be copied to the other sheets in the group.
If you want to group 3 worksheets, the workbook must contain at least 1 more. Otherwise, any selection of a single sheet will remove the grouping.
If you want this to work only on a defined portion of the sheets, use the SheetSelectionChange event to group the sheets when a cell from the defined range is selected, and ungroup when a cell outside this range is selected.
In the following code, I assumed that the sheets named Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3 will be grouped and there will be at least one other sheet in addition to that. The range in which the grouping will work: A1:B5.
Place the code in the workbook module (ThisWorkbook).
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ToSel As Sheets
    Set ToSel = Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"))
    Set Target = Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("A1:B5"))
    If Target Is Nothing Or Not IsIn(Sh, ToSel) Then
        Sh.Select
    Else
        If Not ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets Is ToSel Then
            ToSel.Select
        End If
        Application.Goto Sh.Range(Target.Address)
    End If
End Sub
Function IsIn(wk As Worksheet, shs As Sheets) As Boolean
    Dim s As Worksheet
    For Each s In shs
        If s Is wk Then IsIn = True: Exit Function
    Next s
End Function


This worked great. Did some slight tweaking but never would have got that far with out your assistance!!
